# Multiple Image Directories for single APEX instance

Tags: oracle, alias, oracle-apex

is it somehow possible to define multiple image directories for a single Apex instance? We implemented an Image gallery and the pictures for it are located in the server filesystem. (I know, we should use BLOB but our customer insists on using the filesystem, so I got no choice). The paths to the images are stored in a table, which is filled by a little perl-script. This worked like a charm until they decided to move the images to a different HDD. Filling the table with these new paths works, but APEX doesn't display them because they are outside of the Oracle Instance.

Is it somehow possible to add a second path which can be accessed by APEX without losing the access to the standard /i/?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using XDB, OHS or the APEX Listener? Not sure about XDB or the APEX Listener, but OHS is "just" a web server and you should be able to add an alias in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Yes I am using OHS. Ok I am going to try that. Adding an alias to the config file seems to be rather simple :-)

Comment: I'd consider creating soft links to map the folders into apex's image folder.

Comment: @oraclederd That did it. After some trying I got it to work. Maybe you  would like to add a real answer so I can flag it as correct answer? It  is important, that the last '\' even on a windows system is written as '/'. It won't work with something like Alias /inew/ "E:\data\". It has to be Alias /inew/ "E:\data/" or better Alias /inew/ "E:/data/"

Comment: @Diskilla - I'm glad that worked. I think it would be better if you answered the question (or updated the question itself), I don't know (better, I can't remember) how *exactly* to do that. I merely pointed you in the right direction. :)